# Building a linked list in Java

Tags: java, list, linked-list

This is an example from my book. As I see it, when you create a list with this class, you create two objects (`first` and `last`, which are null). I can't figure out why, when you put both first and last "Node" objects in the add method. Shouldn't it create two elements when you set both `first = n` and `last = n`. For example, if I call `list.add(2)`, shouldn't both `first` and `last` be 2 now ?

```
public class List {

    private Node   first = null;
    private Node   last = null;

    public List(){
        first = null;
        last = null;

    }   

    private static class Node{

        public int   value;
        public Node   next;

        public Node ( int value, Node next){
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;       
        }
    }   

    public void add (int value){
        Node   n = new Node (value,null);

        if(first==null){
            first = n;
            last = n;

        }else{
            last.next = n;
            last = n;
        }
    }

    public int size(){
        int   number = 0;
        Node   n = first;
        while(n != null){
            number++;
            n = n.next;
        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you write unit tests

Answer (score 3):

> As i see it, when u create a list with this class, you create two objects (first and last, which are null).

That's not true. `first` and `last` are not objects, but *references* to objects. And in this case, they start out as *null* references, meaning that they don't refer to any object at all.

When you write `first = n; last = n;`, you set `first` and `last` to both refer to the same object — whatever object `n` refers to.

> For example, if list.add(2), shouldn't now both first and last be 2?

Yes, they'll both refer to the same `Node` instance, whose `value` is 2.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. So, I actually have two elements who point to the same value.

Comment: @user1159186: I wouldn't put it quite that way, no. Since you're talking about a linked-list, "element" sounds like "list element", and "value" sounds like the `value` of a `Node`. Your list has only *one* element. The list *object* has two *fields*, which both point to the same `Node` (i.e., to the same list element). Naturally that `Node` has only one `value`.

Comment: If i were to add another node, lets say, list.add(2), list.add(3) and list.add(4), would now the first = node.value = 2 and last = node.value = 3 or 4?

Comment: @user1159186: Suppose you wrote `List list = new List(); list.add(2); list.add(3); list.add(4);`. Then `list.first.value` would be 2, `list.first.next.value` would be 3, and `list.first.next.next.value` would be 4. Also, `list.last` and `list.first.next.next` would refer to the same object, so `list.last.value` would be 4 and `list.first.next.next.next` would be `null` (since `list.last.next` is *always* `null`).

Comment: So a new "next Node" is created everytime the add method is called?

Comment: @user1159186: You see the line `Node   n = new Node (value,null);`? That creates a new `Node`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i see that first and last are needed.  Probably later on first will be much more useful if you have dequeue (remove first) or a search (which i guess can be done from the end rather than at the start, same process for a simple linear search).

As for your question. Yes if you started with a blank list and said list.add(2).  Both first and last will be pointing to node with value 2.  This is because the first element and the last element in the list are the same, hence 1 element in the list.  Its both first and last (and middle if you want to be weird).

but if you did list.add(1), list.add(2).  You would get first = node.value == 1 and second = node.value == 2

Comment: Re: "First no need for last": That's not true. This class's `add(int)` method adds a new element to the end of the list. If you got rid of the `last` field, that would require iterating through the whole list. (I suppose the functionality would be equivalent, but since you're suggesting changing `size()` to be O(1) rather than O(n), I don't see why you'd call it "weird" that `add(int)` is already O(1) rather than O(n).)

Comment: Wow, i think i get it now. You guys are great!

Comment: wopsy!  of course i did not read that part.  It makes sense.  Your correct.  I did not see the whole add with the last.  For some odd reason in my head i was thinking Queue rather than your standard LinkedList.  I am a dummy here and there